# Understanding pointers and address references in C

Tags: c

So here is an exercise and the gives solution below:

Assume that the following declarations have been made:

```
char c = ‘A’;
char *p = &c;
char **p2 = &p;
void *v = &p2;
```

Examine each of the following expressions. If the expression is illegal, write ILLEGAL. If the expression is legal, write its type (ie. int, void *, etc.)

```
 &p2 : char***
 *p2: char*
 &v: char****
 p2 + 1: char**
 v[0]: Illegal
```

Can you explain how we got such types? I understand that v[0] is illegal because v points to the address, and we cannot use bracket notation to access it as we do with array.
But all other make me a bit confused, especially 1-3.

I would be happy for the help!

Comment: > we cannot use bracket notation to access - why not? v[0] == *(v + 0).

Comment: Actually, `v[0]` is illegal because `v` is a pointer to `void` and a pointer to `void` may not be dereferenced. To quote K&R, "The (nonexistent) value of a void object may not be used in any way..."

Comment: @user3386109, in general, we can use this notation to access - that's what I wanted to say.

Answer (score 3):

For any lvalue expression `e` of type `T`, the expression `&e` has type `T *`, and the value of the expression is the location of `e`.  Similarly, for any expression `p` of type `T *`, the expression `*p` has type `T` and the value of the expression is the value of whatever `p` points to.

The expression `c` has type `char`, so the expression `&c` has type `char *`, and the value of the expression is the location of `c`.  This value is assigned to the variable `p`, which also has type `char *`

Since `p` has type `char *`, the expression `&p` has type `char **` and the value is the location of `p`.  This is assigned to the variable `p2`, which also has type `char **`.

There's a mistake in the answer key; the type of `&v`
 is `void **`, not `char ****`.

`v[0]` is illegal because `v` has type `void *`, and you are not allowed to dereference a void pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the basic variables

```
c: char
p: char* (because p = &c)
p2: char** (because p2 = &p)
v: char*** (because v = &p2)
```

Now, `&` adds one level of indirection, and `*` dereferences, which subtracts one level of indirection.

```
&p2: char*** (because p2 is char**)
*p2: char* (because p2 is char**)
&v: char**** (because v is char***)
p2 + 1: char** (same type as p2)
```

Note that you can (and some people do) write `char *p` as `char* p` which can more easily translated into "variable `p` of type `char*`", same for `char** p`, etc. But `char *p` has somehow become the convention. I personally had a hard time converting when I joined a company that follows the `char *p` convention.

Comment: There's only `void *`, no further indirection, since `void *` essentially means "a pointer (to anything)", and "a pointer to a pointer (to anything)" is still "a pointer". You can actually cast any pointer type (like `char *`, `char **`, `char ***`, etc) to `void *`. But before one uses `void *`, it is usually cast into something more concrete.

Comment: I think that convention was adopted to allow multiple declarations on a single line, e.g. `char *a, *b;`. The line `char* a, b;` declares `a` as a pointer and `b` as a simple `char`.

Comment: @user3386109 Agree. I rarely declares variables on the same line (actually 90% of the time they're initialized with a default value). Still Objective-C adopted the convention, so now I just follow without questions :)

Comment: @KhanhNguyen: not all types can be converted to `void *`. C does not specify behaviour for converting between a pointer to function and `void *`, for example.